# Golang recursive function call with timeout

Tags: go

I wrote a function that should be called every 5 seconds.

```
func (s *cacheService) ReloadCache() {
    // dosmt...

    <- time.After(time.Second * 5)

    s.ReloadCache()
}
```

it looks easier than doing the same thing in a loop. But I wonder if such an implementation has problems with memory? Will the call stack be clogged or smt else?
is this option better?

```
func (s *cacheService) ReloadCache() {
    // dosmt...

    <- time.After(time.Second * 5)

    go s.ReloadCache()
}
```

Comment: "Will the call stack be clogged or smt else?" It's actually quite funny to ask this question on stackoverflow as this is what will happen.

Comment: @Volker 
And if you add go before calling the function, then is this a normal option?

Comment: "it looks easier than doing the same thing in a loop." in what way does that look easier than `for { dosmt(); <- time.After(time.Second * 5)}`? Code obfuscation is generally a bad idea, even if it doesn't make you run out of resources.

Comment: Do you think starting an unbound number of goroutines would help in any way?

Comment: @evrei666 You can look at this example https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools which very easily shows how to set up a worker and only have limited number jobs on the channel at a time. You can rewrite the code that pushes your_function to the worker every 5second.